# AngularFire 6... How do I set languageCode on afAuth?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I've upgraded my AngularFire app from 5 to 6.

On the previous version, setting the languageCode for the Authentication was simple: Set languageCode = "es";

```ts
this.afAuth.auth.languageCode = "es";
```

On AngularFire 6, afAuth directly exposes languageCode, but instead of accepting a string, it expects a promise.

I'm honestly a bit lost here (I'm still learning Angular and Typescript), and there's no documentation on how to set up languageCode on AF6....

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It was pretty simple actually, just return the string as a promise.

This is due PromiseProxy was added in this new version of AngularFire.

from

```ts
this.afAuth.auth.languageCode = "es";
```

to

```ts
this.afAuth.languageCode = new Promise(() => 'es');
```

Comment: Isn't this.afAuth.languageCode =  Promise.resolve('es'); more correct as you explicitly resolve the promise?